# How do I use while and for loops to print asterisks?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am really struggling I don't know how to fix the `for` loop so that if the user inputs is a negative number it shows how many marks are entered in the ranges, I have also taken out some details e.g. the scanner because there was too much code

```
System.out.println("Enter mark, or -1 to finish: ");

    while (mark >= 0) //process data until sentinnel is entered
    {

        mark = (int) input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter another mark, or enter -1 to exit");
        if (mark >= 0) 
        {
            sum = sum + mark;
            count++;

            if ((mark >= 0) && (mark <= 29)) {
                cat1++;
            } else if ((mark >= 30) && (mark <= 39)) {
                cat2++;
            } else if ((mark >= 40) && (mark <= 69)) {
                cat3++;
            } else if ((mark >= 70) && (mark <= 100)) {
                cat4++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
        }//end if
    }//end while
    System.out.println("0 - 29 ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= cat1; i++) {
        for (i = 0; i <= cat1; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
```

Comment: You have sum and mark. how do these relate to each other?

Comment: i used it to work out the average mark

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking abou:

```
    System.out.println("0 - 29 ")
    for (int i = 0; i <= cat1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("30 - 39 ")
    for (int i = 0; i <= cat2; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    System.out.println();
    //and so on
```

Comment: the loop just keeps running :(